# What to do if there is no data in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, local-storage, frontend

I'm in a dilemma, I have a search engine which I keep the last results, everything perfect until there.

The problem is that I do not know what to do if I do not have items already saved, ie if it is the first time I search.

```
if(localStorage.getItem("searchResults") === null) {
  // I do not know what to do here ...
}

else {
  // Here the code is supposed to do what it has to do                 
}
```

Should not I do anything, should I save an empty string, or would I have to change the logic I'm working on?

What are your friends, what are you doing? Thank you

Comment: `// I do not know what to do here ...` - that depends on what you want your code to do, only you can know what your logic would require there

Answer (score 0):

You could set it to N/A:

```
if(localStorage.getItem("searchResults") === null) {
  localStorage.setItem("searchResults", "N/A"); 
}
else {
  // Here the code is supposed to do what it has to do                 
}
```

Or use the following, and when you check if `searchResults` is null, last search result should be empty.

```
if(localStorage.getItem("searchResults") !== null) {
  // Here the code is supposed to do what it has to do
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have a variable called "noResults", and set it to `false`, when search results are 0, or you can make it fetch results from server. It's all about context and logic

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't need an `if` statement. The `if` statement provides you with code blocks that can be executed for truthy or falsely expressions.

Instead, use a logical OR `||` to define a default value.

```
var results = localStorage.getItem('searchResults') || 'No results...';
```